# Eclipse Preferences File

Tags: eclipse

Where does Eclipse store the keyboard shortcuts configured in the Preferences dialog? I have a lot of custom keyboard shortcuts, and I find it's a huge chore to manually re-enter them whenever I setup a in Eclipse installation. I'm assuming Eclipse stores these configurations under ~/.eclipse, but after searching through those file I can't seem narrow down which specific file(s) contain my preferences.

How would I programmatically backup and restore my Eclipse preferences?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to: http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2007/07/eclipse-shortcuts.html

> Go to File > Export > Preferences. Select "Export All" and fill
>   out the destination path in the "To preference file" field. Click
>   "Finish" to output a .epf file. Import these with File > Import >
>   Preferences.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by use of the Import and Export buttons.The currently set preferences are stored in a .epf file that you specify when you export. Any preference that is still set to it's default value will not be saved in this file. When you import from a .epf file any preferences defined in that file will be set to the value stored. Preferences not stored in the .epf file are not affected.

Source : http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Preferences/preferences.htm

Look at these links.This may help you.

http://www.winksaville.com/blog/programming/eclipse-settings-and-moving-workspaces/

http://coskunscastle.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-export-eclipse-workbench-layout.html